# Ubuntu 17.10 powers off without going through the shutdown cycle

Tags: shutdown, systemd

When I shut my laptop down then it powers off almost immediately. It doesn't stop the services properly, and even firefox says it was shutdown improperly.
I have tried 'init 6', 'reboot', 'shutdown', 'systemctl reboot'. It's all behaving the same.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

What documentation are you referencing for your expectations for how shutdown should work?

The docs for `systemd-shutdown` says it will *kill all remaining processes.*

The [systemd.kill](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html) man page explains some of the shutdown logic.

But Firefox would not be a systemd managed service. At best, it's going to receive a TERM signal, and then if it hasn't finished shutting down shortly, it would receive a KILL signal.

If you want Firefox to cleanly exit before you shutdown, you should close it yourself.

Comment: I expected that Systemd shutdown or halt would run the ExecStop commands in the units I defined. But it seems to bluntly pull the power plug out of the wall...

Comment: As seen in `man systemctl`, You have a choice to use `--force` or not, for graceful vs immediate/brutal shutdown. Perhaps your `ExecStop=` directive took too long? Having shutdown logs of timestamps of the specific unit in question would be useful to review.